# How to use Numlock keys in calculator

Tags: c#

I was writing a program of simple calculator. I was able to make the calculator, but the entering is through mouse clicks.

I wanted to know how to use numlock keys for entering numbers.

Comment: You should include what you have attempted so far. [Perhaps check this out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171538(v=vs.110).aspx) (when you handle each key, you should call the same function that the button click event calls)

Comment: Please make sure your question meets the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)!!

Comment: Did you create it as a webform or winform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can get a little tedious, but assuming your application is WPF, here's the [overview of user input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754010%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from MSDN.

The important part is that your window definition (the XAML) can get a `KeyDown` event handler assigned.  If you add it, when you hit `=`, you should be given the opportunity to have the method created.  Do that, and you can figure out what key was pressed and what to do about it.  The MSDN example of it looks like this:

```
private void OnButtonKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    Button source = e.Source as Button;
    if (source != null)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Left)
        {
            source.Background = Brushes.LemonChiffon;
        }
        else
        {
            source.Background = Brushes.AliceBlue;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't recommend the color thing, myself, but you can connect the logic you use for your buttons, instead, too, if you wanted.